Windows can't connect to previously paired bluetooth devices
For as long as I can remember, I haven't been able to connect to previously paired bluetooth devices on my Windows 11 PC; I'm required to unpair them everytime I want to connect them again.
For example, let's say I want to connect a previously paired ("Couplé" in French) Dualsense controller to my PC, I will first have to delete it from "my devices" and pair it again for it to connect.
Here is a gif :

You can see clicking on the "Couplé" (paired) device doesn't do anything, and then after deleting it from my devices and clicking on it again in the "New devices" section it connects normally.
Does anyone know how to allow my PC to connect to paired devices (I can't believe this is even an issue) ?
Edit : I of course have already cleared out drivers and firmware issues. Windows is up to date, my controller's firmware is up to date, my bluetooth drivers are up to date.

Have you checked for updated drivers and firmware for your computer, from the brand's support site?

@music2myear yes, I used the "Firmware updater for DualSense wireless controller" from Sony's website, which says the Dualsense is up to date.

That's not what I asked. Your COMPUTER's drivers and firmware being updated are a first step in diagnosing issues like this. Also, please add any steps and actions you have taken to your main question, so people know that you have done that.

yeah that was my first step. Thought of it as obvious. I'll add it to the question
